# How to detect "driving" mode on Motorola Moto X?

Tags: android

Is there a way for Android app running on Moto X device to detect that Motorola Assist has activated "Driving" mode? If yes, how?

Comment: why dont you use google play service `Activity Recognition API` since that is probably what Moto Assist uses

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - will definitely check it out! However I'm pretty sure Motorola does not use Activity Recognition API, there is no ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission declared in Motorola Assist's manifest

Comment: @tyczj the Activity Recognition API approach worked very well. I'll gladly accept such answer if you provide one